# Extract substring from string python re library

Tags: python, python-re

I have a string

```
string = 'Ph no. : 999999999 | year: 2021 | class no.: 10Type: 2-A | S-no. : dfwef | Name : dfwf'
```

Using regular expression python I want to extract Type. Output I want in this case is 2-A.

I have tried is

```
import re
type = re.findall(r'Type: \d*-', string)
print(type)
```

I have multiples strings of this type and i want to extract code text between 'Type:' and '|'.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Show your code - [mre].

Comment: my guess was for: sub = (((re.split(r"(?:Type:)(.*)", string))[1]).split())[0] but given the answers maybe its not the best choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the needed result if `Type` contains only one number, '-', and a letter

```
import re

string = 'Ph no. : 999999999 | year: 2021 | class no.: 10Type: 2-A | S-no. : dfwef | Name : dfwf'

type_str = re.search('(Type:\s\d+-\w+)', string).group()
print(type_str)
```

> Type: 2-A

Or if you want to extract only the 2-A

```
import re

string = 'Ph no. : 999999999 | year: 2021 | class no.: 10Type: 2-A | S-no. : dfwef | Name : dfwf'

type_str = re.search('(Type:\s\d-\w)', string).group()
print(type_str.split(': ')[1])
```

> 2-A

And finally as requested to extract any text from `Type:` to `|` it will be

```
import re

string = 'Ph no. : 999999999 | year: 2021 | class no.: 10Type: 10 X-ASFD 34 10 | S-no. : dfwef | Name : dfwf'

type_str = re.search('Type:\s(.*?\|)', string).group()
print(type_str.split(': ')[1].replace('|',''))
```

> 10 X-ASFD 34 10

Comment: Suppose i have another string
```
string = 'Ph no. : 999999999 | year: 2021 | class no.: 10Type: 200-A/B | S-no. : dfwef | Name : dfwf'
```
and i want to extract 

200A/B
how should i do this?

Comment: Then `type_str = re.search('(Type:\s\d+-\w+(\/\w){0,1})', string).group()
print(type_str.split(': ')[1])` will cover both of your cases (this regex will extract both 2-A, 200-A/B

Comment: I have multiple strings of this kind. some have type 2-A and some have type 10 A/X. I want to write a single code that works for all strings .
i want to extact string between 'Type:' and '|'.

Comment: On this string `string = 'Ph no. : 999999999 | year: 2021 | class no.: 10Type: 10 X-ASFD 34 10 | S-no. : dfwef | Name : dfwf'` (tried to make it complex) the following code will work  `type_str = re.search('Type:\s(.*?\|)', string).group()
print(type_str.split(': ')[1].replace('|',''))` so this will extract ALL symbols from `Type:` to following `|`

Comment: it is printing '|' also.

Comment: Didn't you forget the `type_str.split(': ')[1].replace('|','')` part? It's crucial to "clean" the string, if you want to do this one line style then it will be `type_str = re.search('Type:\s(.*?\|)', string).group().split(': ')[1].replace('|','')` , if the | still occurs please provide me another example

Comment: thanks
can you please explain re.search('Type:\s(.*?\|)', string).group()   this part

Comment: Sure, it first founds "Type:", then space (\s) then found any symbol (.) any number of times (*?) until it founds "|" (\|), re.search founds valid groups of this regex by given string (`string`), group extracts first (and only in our case) matched regex. Split is splitting string by ": " (space after ":" is intended), cutting the "Type: ", and then replacing "|" with empty symbol

Comment: suppose if i want to extract class number that is 10 in this case but there is no gap between 10 and Type.
i tried re.search('class no.:\s(.*?\|)', string).group().split(': ')[1]
but the output is 10Type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233645/discussion-between-hotkuk-and-sourabh-mittal).

Answer (score 2):

Use regex `'(?<=Type: )[\w-]+'`

- `(?<=Type: )` will extract everything after **Type:**
- `[\w-]+` will extract only *digits*, *words* and *-*

```
import re
re.findall(r'(?<=Type: )[\w-]+',string)
>> ['2-A']
```

Comment: I have multiple strings of this kind. some have type 2-A and some have type 10 A/X.
I want to write a single code that works for all strings